# upload only txt files

Tags: php, file, upload, text-files

how do check so ONLY .txt files are uploaded to the server and not other files in php.

Answer (score 9):

You can test the filetype:

```
if ($_FILES['file']['type'] == 'text/plain') // this file is TXT
```

Also, you can verify the mime-type of a file using the function [mime_content_type](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php).

Comment: After the upload, use the mime_content_type function I posted.

Comment: Isn't it more secure to match the file type using preg_match instead of mime-type?

Comment: @www139 I'd say no because preg_match will be looking at the text which is there, and the extentions like .gif can easily be faked or have the file saved like that, which would mess up the result provided by preg_match. Checking mime types isn't a perfect solution but the extensions alone is a bad check

Answer (score 1):

```
if(preg_match('\.txt$', $filename))
```

This will return true if the file ends with .txt

Comment: but it could be a JPG file w/ a diff extension.

Comment: Any other method requires trusting the user or uploading the whole file first to find out. Besides, most browsers will just open it as a text file despite mime type

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check the actual file MIME type, try PHP's [finfo_file function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php). (See example #1 on that page. If the string returned isn't "text/html," then it's not a text file.)

Edit: Bear in mind that the [mime_content_type](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php) function has been depreciated. Use finfo_file instead.

Comment: @Alexander Girndt - @Jake is right, please don't assume *.txt is same as plain text file

Comment: finfo_file is only standard in PHP 5.3 and newer.  Prior to this, you needed a PECL extension for it.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to check that the extension is ".txt", and it doesn't matter if the file is a real text file, then do:

```
$fileName = ...
$nameLength = strlen($fileName);
if ($nameLength > 4 && substr($fileName, $nameLength - 4) == '.txt')
{
    // Extension is ".txt".
}
else
{
    // Other extension or no extension at all.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [mime_content_type](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php)

Answer (score 0):

Would this code that i wrote work?

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="POST"> 
Välj din txt fil: <input name="uploaded" type="file" /><br /> 
<input type="submit" value="Upload" /> 
</form> 


<?php 
$target = "upload/"; 
$target = $target . basename( $_FILES['uploaded']['name']) ; 
$ok=1;

if ($uploaded_size > 350000) { 
echo "Your file is too large.<br>"; $ok=0; 
}

if ($uploaded_type !=="text/plain") { 
echo "Only txt files allowed<br>"; $ok=0; 
} 

if ($ok==0) { 
echo "Sorry your file was not uploaded"; 
} else { 
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'], $target)) { 
                     echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded"; 
            } else { echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file."; } 
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

how about using [pathinfo()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php)

with something like this:

```
$filename = pathinfo($_FILES['upload']['name']);

$ext = $filename['extension'];

if($ext !== 'txt'){
  //don't upload
}else{
  //upload
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<strong>Upload Serial Number File:</strong>
               <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload"><br><br>  




<?php


// Pass the input field name , file upload success it return TRUE.   
function Get_the_Client_UploadFile($InputfeildName)
{


  $ClientUserName   = gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);   
  $Cient_Uploadfile = "";   // do not remove

$SerialNumberFileuploadOk = FALSE;


    $uploaddir =  'UserInputLog/' ;
    if( is_dir($uploaddir) === false )
    {
        mkdir($uploaddir);
    }


    $Cient_Uploadfile = basename($_FILES[$InputfeildName]['name']);
    if(!empty($Cient_Uploadfile))
    {     


               $Cient_Uploadfile = $uploaddir . $ClientUserName.'_'.basename($_FILES[$InputfeildName]['name']);              
                 //delte old old uplaoded file from logs
              if (file_exists($Cient_Uploadfile))               
                  unlink($Cient_Uploadfile);    //delete     
              //copy here 
              if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$InputfeildName]['tmp_name'], $Cient_Uploadfile)) {
                  Data_Log("File is valid, and was successfully uploaded . $Cient_Uploadfile");
                  $SerialNumberFileuploadOk = TRUE;   
              } else {
                  DisplayMessageDialog("unable to upload file = $Cient_Uploadfile"); 
              }
              //print_r($_FILES);          

               // Allow certain file formats

              $FileType = pathinfo($Cient_Uploadfile,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
              if($FileType != "txt") {
                  DisplayMessageDialog("File Ext ERROR: $FileType Please upload only '.txt' file (Notepad file with serial number)");
                    if (file_exists($Cient_Uploadfile))               
                      unlink($Cient_Uploadfile);    //delete  
                  $SerialNumberFileuploadOk = FALSE;
                 }

             // Check file size
             //we want to check the size of the file. If the file is larger than 5 MB
             if ($_FILES[$InputfeildName]["size"] > 5000000) {
                 DisplayMessageDialog( "Sorry, your file is too large. Allowed only 5 MB");
                  if (file_exists($Cient_Uploadfile))               
                      unlink($Cient_Uploadfile);    //delete  
                 $SerialNumberFileuploadOk = FALSE;
                 }
    }

    if($SerialNumberFileuploadOk == FALSE)
    $Cient_Uploadfile = "";

    return  $SerialNumberFileuploadOk;

}

function DisplayMessageDialog($msg)
{
  echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("' . $msg . '")</script>';
  Data_Log(" *** DialogBox Open *** :  ".$msg);
}
?>
```